# Pandas Series Conditionally Change String

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to change the strings in a Pandas Series by a condition. If the string name is say 'A', it should be 'AA'. The code snippet below works but it is very un elegant and inefficient. I am passing a Pandas series as an argument as I said. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
def conditions(x):
    if x == 'A':
        return "AA"
    elif x == 'B':
        return "BB"
    elif x == 'C':
        return "CC"
    elif x == 'D':
        return "DD"
    elif x == 'E':
        return "EE"
    elif x == 'F':
        return "FF"
    elif x == 'G':
        return "GG"
    elif x == 'H':
        return "HH"
    elif x == 'I':
        return "I"
    elif x == 'J':
        return "JJ"
    elif x == 'K':
        return "KK"
    elif x == 'L':
        return 'LL'

func = np.vectorize(conditions)
test = func(rfqs["client"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to repeat a given string, you can add the string to itself across all rows at once.  If you have some other condition, you can specify that condition and add the string to itself only for rows that meet the criteria.  See this toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'client': ['A', 'B', 'Z']})

df.loc[df['client'].str.contains('[A-L]'), 'client'] = df['client'] * 2
```

to get

```
  client
0     AA
1     BB
2      Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to avoid all those if elses:

```
d = {i:2*i for i in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L')} 

test = rfqs["client"].apply(lambda x: d[x] if x in d else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
l = list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'].isin(l),df['col'].str.repeat(2))
```

With `np.where()`

```
df['col'].mul(np.where(df['col'].isin(l),2,1))
```

With `map()`

```
df['A'].mul(df['A'].map({i:2 for i in l}).fillna(1).astype(int))
```